# How does separating frequencies by Gaussian Filter work?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I want to understand the meaning of separating the frequencies using Gaussian filter. Could you give me a meaningful example?

Comment: The question is more relevant for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, my study area is image processing, so i need to understand in context of image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaussian Kernel is an Low Pass Filter (LPF).
It means that every time it is applied on an image it removes High Frequency Data.

Now think about the following process, you apply LPF on an image, the resulted image is called LPF_k.
Now you take Image_k (Original image at the k-th step) and get HPF_k = Image_k - LPF_k.
Why HPF (High Pass Filter)? Because you took the image which contains all frequencies and remove from it the LPF part of it which leaves you with the HPF.

It means now you seprated the LPF data of an image and the HPF.

If you insert Downsampling and Upsampling process in between you can split the frequencies as you want (Filter Banks).

This is how Equalizer work for example.

You can read more in [Filter Banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank).

This actually what lies behind Wavelets, Multi Scale Analysis and Pyramid Decomposition in Image Processing.

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian Filters are widely used in the image processing.

In image processing, one very important task is to remove white noise, all the while maintaining salient edges. This can be a contradictory task - white noise exists at all frequencies equally, while edges exist in the high frequency range.

How then, to remove noise, but also preserve high frequency edges? Enter the Gaussian kernel. Since the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian is also a Gaussian, the Gaussian filter does not have a sharp cutoff at some pass band frequency beyond which all higher frequencies are removed. Instead, it has a graceful and natural tail that becomes ever lower as the frequency increases. This means that it will act as a low pass filter, but also allow in higher frequency components.

Look for more details at:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/why-are-gaussian-filters-used-as-low-pass-filters-in-image-processing
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16623/intuition-behind-the-gaussian-filter-in-image-processing